# Capture mediaelement events

Tags: plugin-development, media, video-player

I'm trying to capture a couple of media element player events to no avail.  There's a great [API list of events](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md) available, but little documentation on how to implement. No examples.  Here's what I've tried:

```
        mejs.players[id].media.on('play',function(){
            console.log('playing');
        });

        mejs.players[id].media.events.on('play',function(){
            console.log('playing');
        });

        mejs.players[id].container.on('play',function(){
            console.log('playing');
        });
```

Looking at the `mejs.players[id]` object in the Chrome console shows that there's `mejs.players[id].media.events.play (canplay, playing, pause etc)` events, but when I try

```
        mejs.players[id].media.events.on('play',function(){
            console.log('playing');
        });
```

I get

> mejs.players[id].media.on is not a function

Comment: Not using the library. But IMO, the `id` here is a unique id of a media element. Did you assign the unique id of element to `id` variable before?

Comment: yes.  Using jQuery to loop through `$("[id^=mep]").each(function(index, element) {`...  Just to confirm I'm getting the correct IDs, I can confirm that I can control each player with `mejs.players[id].media.play()`